# Is this standard way to derive from singleton class?

Tags: c++, singleton

My Base class is Singleton having protected c'tor. Now, I can derive another class from it but I cannot create instance of that Base class inside functions of derived class. This is expected behavior as per my design. But I like to know is it correct by C++ standards or just my compiler specific behavior? (So that I shouldn't face issues if I want to port this code in future)

```
class Singleton
{
protected:
    Singleton() {}

public:
    Singleton * GetInstance()
    {
        static Singleton* InstanceCreated = NULL ;

        if (!InstanceCreated)
            InstanceCreated = new Singleton ;

        return InstanceCreated ;
    }
};

class Deringlton : public Singleton
{
public:
    Deringlton()
    {
        Singleton * pSing ;
        // pSing = new Singlton ; // Cannot create object of singlton 
                                  // (Despite class is derived from singlton)
    }
};
```

Comment: I don't think using singletons is a good design idea primarily. If you want to create derived singleton classes you'd be better of using a [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) singleton base.

Comment: @g-makulik thats exactly what I think. Without the template, all derived classes share the same static instance pointer.

Comment: You don't derive from a singleton.  It doesn't make sense.  By definition, there is only one instance of a singleton.  And the purpose of derivation is to provide different implementations for different objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have to make a singleton (which you should avoid) the instance and(!) the declaration are a singleton. You could use a template have a 'generic' one, but inheritance is no good.

Answer (score 4):

I think a better way to provide a generic singleton implementation is to use the [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) and directly inheriting from that template. That means every class automagically implements the singleton pattern only inheriting from the CRTP base:

```
template<typename DERIVED>
class generic_singleton
{
private:
    static DERIVED* _instance;

    static void _singleton_deleter() { delete _instance; } //Function that manages the destruction of the instance at the end of the execution.

protected:
    generic_singleton() {}
    virtual ~generic_singleton() {} //IMPORTANT: virtual destructor

public:
    DERIVED& instance() //Never return pointers!!! Be aware of "delete Foo.instance()"
    {
        if(!_instance)
        {
            _instance = new DERIVED;
            std::atexit( _singleton_deleter ); //Destruction of instance registered at runtime exit (No leak).
        }
        return static_cast<DERIVED&>( _instance );
    }
};

template<typename DERIVED>
DERIVED* generic_singleton<DERIVED>::_instance = nullptr;
```

The memory release is provided by registering a function that does the delete at the end of the application, with `std::ateexit()`.

Comment: please add ``DERIVED operator=(const DERIVED& rv);`` to prevent assignment.

Comment: you should change the line of :``return static_cast<DERIVED&>( _instance );`` to ``return static_cast<DERIVED&>( *_instance );``

Comment: Also you can define ``_instance`` variable as ``static`` inside of ``instance()`` function and get rid of outside of class initialization.

Comment: I think there is no need to delete the ``_instance`` variable. Because at exit all allocated memory will be released by OS. Am I right ?

Answer (score 1):

What's the point of having a pointer an not just a static variable?

```
class Singleton
{
public:
    static Singleton& instance()
    { static Singleton z; return z; }
private:
    Singleton() {}
    ~SIngleton() {}
};
```

In don't see any value in deriving it.

If you want to make this pattern coded as a template you can do

```
template<class S>
S& instance_of() { static S z; return z; }
```

and make `instance_of<yourclass>()` a friend of `yourclass`, having private ctor / dtor.

The use of a static variable makes the object granted to be properly constructed and destructed. (Unlike a remaining leaked pointer, with no destructor call...)

Comment: To answer your first question: the leaky-singleton pattern avoids the "destruction order fiasco" that you get with the static-local pattern. Of course, it introduces potential data races as well as the leak itself - there is no "correct" way to implement an automatically created singleton in C++.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: If all globals are static initialized on demand inside function bodies, there is no such "fiasco": C++11 grants proper destruction order (inverse construction if independent, same as construction if constructed nestedly) and avoid all the mutithreading issues. Unless until the linking is static.

Comment: The guaranteed destruction order doesn't prevent another static object from accessing this one after destruction. In fact, it makes that error more likely: if this object were created by another static object, then it's guaranteed to be destoyed first, with nothing to prevent the other object trying to access it afterwards. That's the "fiasco" I'm referring to.

Comment: No, if a static object is created by another static object constructor, will be destroyed AFTER. It's one of the C++11 vs 03 changes.

Comment: If it's created by the other object's constructor, then you're right (since its constructor completes first). But it's still entirely possible for one static object to obtain a reference to another that will be destroyed first in a variety of ways, so the "fiasco" I mentioned is a genuine danger.

Comment: Yes, but that's not related to singletons. It's a danger that is proper of whatever reference: it can refer to a not anymore existent object. I don't see any peculiarity. I suspect you are prejudicially influenced by outdated "effective" books...

Comment: All I said was that the leaky pattern avoids this issue, since you asked what the point was. Why are we still arguing?

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behaviour. The rule is you can only access protected members in `Deringlton` if the pointer is of type `Deringlton`. You *cannot* access protected members through a pointer of type `Singleton`. For example:

```
Deringlton* d = this;
d->someProtectedMethod(); // OK!
Singleton* s = this;
s->someProtectedMethod(); // Will fail
```

Since accessing `new Singleton` is not through a `Deringlton` pointer, it is not allowed. You can only access it through Deringlton by doing `new Deringlton`.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is specified in the standard.

Section 11.4 [class.protected] of C++11 states (emphasis mine):

> As described earlier, access to a `protected` member is granted because
>   the reference occurs in a friend or member of some class `C`. If the
>   access is to form a pointer to member (5.3.1), the
>   nested-name-specifier shall denote C or a class derived from C. **All
>   other accesses involve a (possibly implicit) object expression
>   (5.2.5). In this case, the class of the object expression shall be `C`
>   or a class derived from `C`.**

What this means is that access to the base constructor is granted *only if you are creating an object of the derived class*. So for example, this would compile:

```
Deringlton()
{
    Deringlton* p = new Deringlton();
}
```